# fullcalendar how run eventClick from my function

Tags: fullcalendar

how I can run eventClick function defined in fullcalendar in my function called. When I call:

```
$('#kalendar').fullCalendar.trigger('eventClick', eventID);
```

browser return typeerror, that trigger is not function. How I trigger mouse click on specific event or call eventClick on specific event to run eventClick, where is programmed edit dialogue?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar provides [eventClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) function in it's configuration as below.

```
$('#kalendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
        alert('View: ' + view.name);

        // change the border color just for fun
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solve my question...

> add event id to DIV.fc-content - a tag, which will be better, but
>   it can't access on this time, is maybe created after event render?

```
eventRender: function(event, element, calEvent){
                var icon = $('<div />');

                icon.css('width',"12px");
                icon.css('height',"12px");
                icon.css('margin',"2px 3px 0 0");
                icon.css('display',"inline-block");
                icon.css('vertical-align',"text-top");

                if(event.status == "CONFIRMED")
            icon.css('background-image',"url(images/ico_accept12w.png)");
                else
                    icon.css('background-image',"url(images/ico_help12w.png)");

                element.find('.fc-content').attr("id", "event-"+ event.id); // add event id
        element.find('.fc-title').prepend(icon);
            },
```

my function to call click event:

> it's called click trigger on parent a tag on DIV.fc-content

```
function zobrazUdalost(id, datum)
        {
            $('#kalendar<%= idKalendare %>').fullCalendar('gotoDate', moment(datum)); // to go event day
            var events = $('#kalendar<%= idKalendare %>').fullCalendar('clientEvents', id);

            if(events.length > 0){
        $("#event-"+ id).parents("a.fc-day-grid-event").trigger("click"); // call click trigger
        }
        }
```